# Using laravel 5.4 with Socialite ClientException Facebook error "This authorization code has been used"

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm having a very weird problem.

I use Facebook login on my website.
I't randomly fails and randomly works...

Sometimes when i click login with Facebook it works and logs in/creates account. Then i logout and login again and it fails. when i then keep trying to login it will randomly login again in between errors.

Error:

```
(1/1) ClientException
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"B1P9nm3GRb (truncated...)
```

[image]

I am currently on the latest version of Socialite.

Callback function on socialcontroller:

```
$user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());

auth()->login($user);


return redirect()->to('/home');
```

SocialAccountService:

```
public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
{

    $account = SocialAccount::where('provider_user_id', $providerUser->getId())->first();

    if ($account) {

        return $account->user;

    } else {

        $user = User::where('facebook', $providerUser->getId())->first();

        if (!$user) {

            $password = Hash::make($providerUser->getId());
            $user = User::create([
                'username' => $providerUser->getName(),
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'avatar' => $providerUser->getAvatar(),
                'facebook' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'password'=> $password,
                'level' => 0
            ]);

            $account = SocialAccount::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'facebook'
            ]);

        }


        return $user;

    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What if you have not stable slow internet and eventually you send two requests? What if your server have some problems with that? Have you tested the code on another server with the same soft?

Comment: Same issue, tested on two different servers

Answer (score 0):

In your config/session.php file there is a the following line :

```
 `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'your-domain-here'),`
```

Note, it can be `'localhost'`

then just clear your cache : `php artisan cache:clear`

Then resend your request to facebook.